# Is there a way to add a log writer factory into the logger configuration?

Tags: zend-framework2

I write logger config and used Zend\Log\LoggerServiceFactory for configure Logger. If I use base writers all work. But I want add to a logger my own writer who created by factory, and this is donn`t work.

Is there a way to use config and base logger factory to add writer from own factory?

**Update**: here is my code

This is my config where I define factory for Logger, factory for writer and configs for base writers

```
// config/autoload/global.php

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Logger'  => 'Zend\Log\LoggerServiceFactory',
            'Rollbar' => 'Yassa\Rollbar\Log\Writer\Rollbar'
        ),
    ),
    'log' => array(
        'writers' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'stream',
                'options' => array(
                    ...
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'stream',
                'options' => array(
                    ...
                ),
            ),
           array(
               'name' => 'Rollbar',
           ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

`Yassa\Rollbar\Log\Writer\Rollbar` - it`s a factory from yassa\rollbar module ([github](https://github.com/bladeofsteel/yassa-rollbar))

Without Rollbar writer this config does what I need - create and configure standart writers.

Thus I call logger from aontroller:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Logger')->info('test');
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code to help you

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Add code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The solution is not very nice, but nothing better I figured it out.

I wrote a replacement for standard factory (`\Zend\Log\LoggerServiceFactory`) and transfer  logger configuration from the Logger constructor in the my factory. In addition, I added a check for the writer factory.

Here is the resulting class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Factory;

use Zend\Log\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class LoggerServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // Configure the logger
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $options = isset($config['log']) ? $config['log'] : array();
        $logger = new Logger();
        if (is_array($options)) {
            if (isset($options['writers']) && is_array($options['writers'])) {
                foreach ($options['writers'] as $writer) {

                    if (!isset($writer['name'])) {
                        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Options must contain a name for the writer');
                    }

                    $priority      = (isset($writer['priority'])) ? $writer['priority'] : null;
                    $writerOptions = (isset($writer['options'])) ? $writer['options'] : null;

                    if ($serviceLocator->has($writer['name'])) {
                        $writer = $serviceLocator->get($writer['name']);
                        $logger->addWriter($writer, $priority, $writerOptions);
                    } else {
                        $logger->addWriter($writer['name'], $priority, $writerOptions);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isset($options['exceptionhandler']) && $options['exceptionhandler'] === true) {
                Logger::registerExceptionHandler($logger);
            }

            if (isset($options['errorhandler']) && $options['errorhandler'] === true) {
                Logger::registerErrorHandler($logger);
            }

        }
        return $logger;
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I researched the component code and did not find a way to use the factory to create my own writer. Unfortunately currently this is not possible.